# How to generate a hash for my Android app?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm using this guide to implement an autocomplete funcionality in an app I'm working on, but when I try to test it in different computers it returns me a different hash https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/verify-otp-automatically-in-android-without-sms-read-permission-using-xamarin-fo/

The helper class used is the following:

```
using System.Text;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Util;
using Java.Security;
using Java.Util;

namespace InteliMobile.App.Droid.Service
{
    public class AppHashKeyHelper
    {
        private static string HASH_TYPE = "SHA-256";
        private static int NUM_HASHED_BYTES = 9;
        private static int NUM_BASE64_CHAR = 11;

        private static string GetPackageSignature(Context context)
        {
            var packageManager = context.PackageManager;
            var signatures = packageManager.GetPackageInfo(context.PackageName, PackageInfoFlags.Signatures).Signatures;
            return signatures.First().ToCharsString();
        }
  
        public static string GetAppHashKey(Context context)
        {
            string keystoreHexSignature = GetPackageSignature(context);
            string appInfo = context.PackageName + " " + keystoreHexSignature;

            try
            {
                var messageDigest = MessageDigest.GetInstance(HASH_TYPE);
                messageDigest.Update(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appInfo));
                byte[] hashSignature = messageDigest.Digest();

                hashSignature = Arrays.CopyOfRange(hashSignature, 0, NUM_HASHED_BYTES);
                string base64Hash = Android.Util.Base64.EncodeToString(hashSignature, Base64Flags.NoPadding | Base64Flags.NoWrap);
                base64Hash = base64Hash.Substring(0, NUM_BASE64_CHAR);

                return base64Hash;
            }
            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the hash without using a bash script, since the server runs in a Windows machine? Is it safe to deploy the app to production with the helper class in it?

Comment: why do you need a hash for autocomplete?

Comment: @Jason the sms retriever api needs one https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview

Comment: What does that have to do with autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't compute the hash client side.  It's sent from the server, and the instructions to do so are at https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string

You don't do it in code at all, you do it via command line tools.